# Unable to create a tensorflow tfrecord for an image label

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Hi I want to create a tfrecord for images and their one hot array labels.Im able to acheive it for the images,but not for the labels.I referred to this [SOF link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668485/create-an-int-list-feature-to-save-as-tfrecord-in-tensorflow),but getting the same error.Below is my code.

```
def _int64_feature(value):
return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))


def _bytes_feature(value):
return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))


for i in range(len(train_addrs)):

  print('reading image no {0} : and image address {1}'.format(i,train_addrs[i]))

  img = load_image(train_addrs[i])#loading the preprocessed image

  label = train_labels[i]#loading associated one-hot array

  print('label is ',label) #array([0, 1]) of type uint8 ,I tried with int64,int32 also;but no use

  feature = {'train/label':_int64_feature(label),
             'train/image':_bytes_feature(tf.compat.as_bytes(img.tostring())) #this part works 
           }    


  example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))

  serToString = example.SerializeToString()

  writer.write(serToString)
```

When I execute this code,Im getting the following error.

```
 TypeError: array([0, 1]) has type <type 'numpy.ndarray'>, but expected one of: (<type 'int'>, <type 'long'>)
```

Im not sure where am I going wrong?Any help would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since you defined label as `_int64_feature`, you have to use a int for label not a `numpy array`

```
  label = train_labels[i]#loading associated one-hot array
  label = np.argmax(label)
```

you can convert them to `one_hot` format while reading the data.

If you want to pass it as a list; modify your function definition

```
def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ishant .But in the above link,Steven has passed a list,it seems.Is that possible?

Comment: yes ! you need to modify your function for that, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank u very much ishant..could you suggest some tutorials on feeding the data to tensorflow pipeline for training?;

Comment: you can refer https://indico.io/blog/tensorflow-data-inputs-part1-placeholders-protobufs-queues/